# ADF Access to ADLS Gen2 within VNet

Tags: azure-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-network, azure-nsg

I'm looking for some assistance in configuring an ADLS Gen2 which has the firewall enabled and is joined to a VNet so that I can connect to it from ADF.

If I add the [IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses) for the Azure IR to the storage firewall, without the adding the VNet, the linked service connection is successful, however, when I add the VNet to the storage, the connection test fails with the generic error message as if the firewall is blocking the connection.

I have also tried adding the Azure IR IP addresses / DataFactory service tag to the NSG as an inbound rule but this makes no difference, the connection still fails.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the VNets to the firewall of the storage account, it means that you enable a Service endpoint for Azure Storage within the VNet, In this case, you are [allowed access storage only from specific subnets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#grant-access-from-a-virtual-network).

Currently, Data Factory is now a **Trusted Service** [exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#exceptions) in the Azure Storage firewall.
Integration runtime (Azure, Self-hosted, and SSIS) can now connect to Storage without having to be inside the same virtual network or requiring you to allow all inbound connections to the service.

**Steps** to connect to Azure Storage (using Azure blob or Azure Data lake Gen2 linked service) as ‘Trusted Service’ from [this blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/data-factory-is-now-a-trusted-service-in-azure-storage-and-azure/ba-p/964993).

1. Grant Data Factory’s Managed identity access to read data in storage’s access control. For more detailed instructions, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage#managed-identity).
2. Create the linked service using Managed identities for Azure resources authentication
3. Modify the firewall settings in Azure Storage account to select ‘Allow trusted Microsoft Services…’.

For more references: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-secure-your-azure-data-factory-pipeline-e2450502cd43

Comment: I'd just spotted that I wasn't using the Managed Identity to authenticate on the linked service prior to reading your response. Accepting your answer as #2 is what I did to solve my problem.